# Deadlock using LockFile

Tags: c, windows, locking, deadlock, file-locking

I have two threads where I need to read and write the same file, and the portion of file I have to read and write have to be locked. 
In particular I read a custom struct (`account_t`) using a specific offset, I update this structure and I write it again at the same offset.

Following is the main part of the code:

```
if (LockFileEx(handle, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, 0, sizeof(account_t), 0, &ov))
{
    // read account using ov as offset
    // update the account
    // write the account using ov as offset

    UnlockFile(handle, filePos.LowPart, filePos.HighPart, sizeof(account_t), 0);
}
```

Where `ov` is always:

```
LARGE_INTEGER filePos;
OVERLAPPED ov = { 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL }; 

filePos.QuadPart = myOffset;
ov.Offset = filePos.LowPart;
ov.OffsetHigh = filePos.HighPart;
```

The problem is that I have a deadlock when for example:

1. `Thread 1` locks the first account (offset 0)
2. `Thread 2` tries to lock the first account (offset 0) and it waits until the lock is released by the `Thread 1` (as expected)
3. `Thread 1` unlocks the first account (offset 0)

Well, at point 3 the `Thread 1` remains blocked too.
Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know that `Thread 1` remains blocked? I ask because the first bit of the `LockFileEx` documentation says "Locks the specified file for exclusive access by the calling **process**." So maybe file locks don't work for threads in the same process and you need another form of coordination. Just a guess, though.

Comment: When you say `Thread 1` remains blocked, what exactly happens?  Do you mean that the thread never returns from the call to `UnlockFile`?  When you break into the process using the debugger, what is shown on the call stack for that thread?  Have you tried using `UnlockFileEx` instead?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes, the thread never returns from the call to UnlockFile. I'll try using UnlockfileEx...

Comment: Another thought: is the handle synchronous or asynchronous?  I don't think you're allowed to use a synchronous handle in more than one thread simultaneously.